# Prolbems with stage pioneer and laser/rangers on fuerte

Tags: simulation, laser, stage, ros-fuerte, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have problems to use my stage simulation with the default pioneer robot.
I got messages like:

```
ROS Stage currently supports rangers with 1 sensor only.
```

or

```
number of position models and laser models must be equal in the world file.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34661/prolbems-with-stage-pioneer-and-laser/rangers-on-fuerte/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### The current *stageros* implementation supports only one ranger/laser sensor per robot.

**You have to use a stage model without sonar to use the laser sensor.**

Attached you will find my cave-pionee.world which includes a working pioneer stage simulation. The background file cave.png must be in the same folder to get it working

```
# cave-pionee.world 
# simple cave environment with a pioneer robot based on the basic world file examples of 
# Richard Vaughan Richard Vaughan, Andrew Howard, Luis Riazuelo
# Authors: Markus Bader


define hokuyolaser ranger
(
  sensor(       
    # laser-specific properties
    # factory settings for LMS200  
    range [ 0.0  5.0 ]
    fov 270.0
    samples 270
  )
  model
  (
    # generic model properties
    size [ 0.07 0.07 0.05 ] # dimensions from LMS200 data sheet  
    color "blue"
  )
)

define my_block model
(
  size [0.5 0.5 0.5]
  gui_nose 0
)


define floorplan model
(
  # sombre, sensible, artistic
  color "gray30"

  # most maps will need a bounding box
  boundary 1

  gui_nose 0
  gui_grid 0

  gui_outline 0
  gripper_return 0
  fiducial_return 0
  laser_return 1
)

# set the resolution of the underlying raytrace model in meters
resolution 0.02

interval_sim 100  # simulation timestep in milliseconds


# configure the GUI window
window
(
  size [ 635.000 666.000 ] # in pixels
  scale 36.995   # pixels per meter
  center [ -0.040  -0.274 ]
  rotate [ 0  0 ]
        
  show_data 1              # 1=on 0=off
)

# load an environment bitmap
floorplan
( 
  name "cave"
  size [16.000 16.000 0.800]
  pose [0 0 0 0]
  bitmap "cave.png"
)
# set the resolution of


# throw in a robot
my_block( pose [ 5 4 0 180.000 ] color "green")


define pioneer_base position 
(
  color "red"      # Default color.
  drive "diff"       # Differential steering model.
  gui_nose 1                    # Draw a nose on the robot so we can see which way it points
  obstacle_return 1             # Can hit things.
  ranger_return 0.5              # reflects sonar beams
  blob_return 1                 # Seen by blobfinders  
  fiducial_return 1             # Seen as "1" fiducial finders

  localization "gps"             
  localization_origin [0 0 0 0]   # Start odometry at (0, 0, 0).

  # alternative odometric localization with simple error model
  # localization "odom"             # Change to "gps" to have impossibly perfect, global odometry
  #  odom_error [ 0.05 0.05 0.1 ]     # Odometry error or slip in X, Y and Theta
                                     # (Uniform random distribution)   

  # four DOF kinematics limits
  # [ xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax amin amax ]        
  velocity_bounds [-0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 -90.0 90.0 ]          
  acceleration_bounds [-0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 -90 90.0 ]
)



define pioneer2dx_base_no_sonar pioneer_base
(
  # actual size
  size [0.44 0.38 0.22] # sizes from MobileRobots' web site

  # the pioneer's center of rotation is offset from its center of area
  origin [-0.04 0 0 0]

  # draw a nose on the robot so we can see which way it points
  gui_nose 1

  # estimated mass in KG
  mass 23.0 
  # differential steering model
  drive "diff"
 )

# as above, but with front sonar only
define pioneer2dx_no_sonar pioneer2dx_base_no_sonar
(  
  # simplified Body shape:
  block( 
    points 8
    point[0] [-0.2 0.12]
    point[1] [-0.2 -0.12]
    point[2] [-0.12 -0.2555]
    point[3] [0.12 -0.2555]
    point[4] [0.2 -0.12]
    point[5] [0.2 0.12]
    point[6] [0.12 0.2555]
    point[7] [-0.12 0.2555]
    z [0 0.22]
  )
)


pioneer2dx_no_sonar 
(
  # can refer to the robot by this name
  name "r0"
  pose [ -7 -7 0 45 ] 
  hokuyolaser(pose [ 0.225 0.000 -0.15 0.000 ])
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-23**:
Which current stageros are you describing? Electric has stage 3.2.1, with one laser. Fuerte has stage 4.1.1, which replaces the laser interface with ranger.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-05-28**:
ros fuerte uses stage 4.1.1 as default

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-07-06**:
@Markus Bader Thanks, great help - chances are that I will 'steal' your code into my git repository ! Also this works just fine in Hydro !